# Sql Server how to find values in different tables that have different suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm struggling to find a value that might be in different tables but using UNION is a pain as there are a lot of tables.

```
[Different table that contains the suffixes from the TestTable_]
| ID       |      Name|
| -------- | -----------|
| 1        | TestTable1 |
| 2        | TestTable2 |
| 3        | TestTable3 |
| 4        | TestTable4 |

TestTable1 content:
| id       | Name   | q1           |   a1 |
| -------- | ---------------------------------------- |
| 1        | goose  | withFeather? |featherID         |
| 2        | rooster| withoutFeather?|shinyfeatherID  |
| 3        | rooster| age            | 20             |

TestTable2 content:
| id       | Name              | q1             |   a1 |
| -------- | ---------------------------------------------------|
| 1        | brazilian_goose  | withFeather?   |featherID       |
| 2        | annoying_rooster | withoutFeather?|shinyfeatherID  |
| 3        | annoying_rooster | no_legs?       |dead            |

TestTable3 content:
| id       | Name   | q1           |   a1 |
| -------- | ---------------------------------------- |
| 1        | goose  | withFeather? |featherID         |
| 2        | rooster| withoutFeather?|shinyfeatherID  |
| 3        | rooster| age            | 15             |
```

---

Common columns: q1 and a1

Is there a way to parse through all of them to lookup for a specific value without using UNION because some of them might have different columns?

Something like: check if "q1='age'" exists in all those tables (from 1 to 50)
Select q1,*
from (something)
where q1 exists in (TestTable_*)... or something like that.

If not possible, not a problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what question you are trying to answer, for example: "In which table(s) does column q1 equal 42?" or "In which table(s) does q1 equal a1?" It's unclear to me what exactly you mean by "a value that might be in different tables".

Comment: If you want all the data in one dataset with easy access, don't store them on different tables. If you have multiple tables and want them in one dataset you **need** to `JOIN` or `UNION (ALL)` them. There is no `SELECT {Columns} FROM dbo.[Test_Table_*]` syntax. Seems like the problem is your design.

Comment: If you have a bad data model -- such as splitting entities across tables -- then you have to suffer through things like the "pain" of using `union`.  Fix the data model, so you have only one table.

Comment: IT sounds like you have a design not befitting of the requirements. You might have to consider a task that queries each table and creates searchable results in a master index type table, or alternatively Dynamic Sql could be a solution, hard to say without a concrete example.

Comment: updated a bit. unfortunately cannot change anything at the tables .

Comment: This appears to be a very non-relational data design.  In SQL databases that typically causes problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL but something I do in situations like this where I have a list of tables that I want to quickly perform the same actions on is to either use a spreadsheet to paste the list of tables into and type a query into the cell with something like @table then use the substitute function to replace it.

Alternative I just paste the list into SSMS and use SHIFT+ALT+ArrowKey to select the column and start typing stuff out.

So here is my list of tables

[image: List of Tables]

Then I use that key combo.  As you can see my cursor has now selected all those rows.

[image: list of tables with cursor]

Now I can start typing and all rows selected will get the input.

[image: list of tables with repeated input]

Then I just go to the other side of the table names and repeat the action

[image: Completed query]

It's not a perfect solution but it's quick a quick and dirty way of doing something repetitive quickly.

If you want to find all the tables with that column name you can use information schema.

```
Select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'q1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the type of solution you are after I can offer a method that I've had to use on legacy systems.

You can query `sys.columns` for the name of the column(s) you need to find in N tables and join using object_id to `sys.tables where type='U'`. This will give you a list of table names.

From this list you can then build a working query for each table, and depending on your requirements (is this ad-hoc?) either just manually execute it yourself of build a procedure that will do it for you using `sp_executesql`

Eg

```
select t.name, c.name
into #workingtable
from sys.columns c 
join sys.tables t on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name in .....
```

psudocode:

> begin loop while rows exist in #working table
>
> select top 1 row from #workingtable
>
> set @sql=your query specific to that table and column(s)
>
> exec(@sql) / sp_executesql / try/catch as necessary
>
> delete row from working table
>
> end loop

Hopefully that give ideas at least for how you might implement your requirements.